# How to find coords of a specific point on an image?

Tags: python, image, opencv, colors, coordinates

I am trying to get specific coordinates in an image. I have marked dots and rectangles manually on the image (figure 2) at several locations to show you the coordinates I want to get (White dots for walls, pink dots for windows and rectangles for columns). I am using python and opencv to do so but I am not sure whether I'm on the right track or not. Here is an example of the image I am dealing with (figure 1).
[figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCIUR.jpg)
[figure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgczP.png)
Here is my first attempt:

```
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray = np.float32(gray)
    cv2_imshow(gray)
    dst = cv2.cornerHarris(gray,5,3,0.04)
    ret, dst = cv2.threshold(dst,0.1*dst.max(),255,0)
    dst = np.uint8(dst)
    ret, labels, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(dst)
    criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 100, 0.001)
    corners = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray,np.float32(centroids),(5,5),(-1,-1),criteria)
    for i in range(1, len(corners)):
        print(corners[i])
    img[dst>0.1*dst.max()]=[255,255,255]
```

[First attemp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSoY5.png)

EDIT:
-I want to restore the wall center line except for the door/window area.
[Here is an image for that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64fBC.png)
-For the windows/doors, I want to consider the following:
[Doors/windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aMOh.png)

Comment: You forgot to include your attempt to solve this problem.

Comment: I will edit it right away.

Answer (score 0):

The code need some adjustments
Added a step to draw green circles on the original image to visually mark the detected corner points and
sorted the corner points by their response strength, which makes it easier to identify the most significant corners and
adjusted the parameters for Harris corner detection to better suit your specific image and application.

**updated example:**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load the image
img = cv2.imread('jCIUR.jpg')

# Convert the image to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Calculate the Harris corner response function
gray = np.float32(gray)
dst = cv2.cornerHarris(gray, 2, 3, 0.04)  # You can adjust the parameters

# Threshold the Harris response to find corner points
ret, dst = cv2.threshold(dst, 0.1 * dst.max(), 255, 0)
dst = np.uint8(dst)

# Find connected components and refine corner points
ret, labels, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(dst)
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 100, 0.001)
corners = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray, np.float32(centroids), (5, 5), (-1, -1), criteria)

# Print and draw the corner points on the original image
for corner in corners:
    x, y = corner[0], corner[1]
    print(f"Corner at ({x},{y})")
    cv2.circle(img, (int(x), int(y)), 5, (0, 255, 0), -1)  # Draw a green circle

# Display the image with marked corners
cv2.imshow('Corners', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: The points were massive whereas I needed only a few ones. I edited my post. please take a look at it.